# exclude find query fields while inserting document using upsert:true

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.getCollection('placeFollow').update(
{
    "_id":ObjectId("5af19959204438676c0d5268"),
    "count":{"$lt":2}
 },
 {   
     "$set":{"data":"check"}
  },
  {"upsert":true})
```

> Error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: geoFame.placeFollow
>   index: id dup key: { : ObjectId('5af19959204438676c0d5268') }

**Indexes**

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "geoFame.placeFollow"
    }
]
```

I want to  save the document if it doesn't exist. But above query is trying to insert _id, which is given in find query and it is throwing duplicate key error. How to exclude find query while inserting the document?

Comment: No it is not. Show the actual error being returned. The `_id` is immutable and cannot be changed, so the error is actually something different.

Comment: E11000 duplicate key error collection: geoFame.placeFollow index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5af19959204438676c0d5268') }

Comment: That's not true. `update()` cannot do that. Show the actual document you are trying to update in the collection and any indexes present. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50523941/edit) and do not post details in comments. Also add the MongoDB version you are currently using, as you might just be using a development release

Comment: I see your bug now. You don't actually ever `$set` the `"count" field. Hence the duplicate key error

Comment: I have added the count field to $set, still is throwing duplicate key error

Comment: You need to delete the existing document first because it does not have a "count". See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is of course supplying the `_id`, but you need to actually set the `"count"` field as well. Using [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is probably what you want:

```
db.getCollection('placeFollow').update(
  { "count":{"$lt":2} },
  {   
     "$set":{ "data": "check" },
     "$setOnInsert": { "count": 2 }
  },
  {"upsert":true}
)
```

So you need to do something like that with whatever "default" or otherwise expected data should be in there. Otherwise MongoDB does not find a document because the field is not there and attempts inserting with the same `_id` value as provided.

Because your code is currently incorrect you need to remove the document which was created without the `"count"` first:

```
db.getCollection('placeFollow').deleteOne(
  { "_id":ObjectId("5af19959204438676c0d5268") }
)
```

Either that or set all documents with a default value of `count.

But basically you cannot use both an "primary key" and another condition when using "upsert", because if the document does not meet the condition then the upsert is attempted, and of course an existing value for `_id` is unique.

Comment: E11000 duplicate key error collection: geoFame.placeFollow index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5af19959204438676c0d5268') }

Comment: @MohammadJilani Read. You cannot use the `_id`. Any document which has that value and does not meet the other condition means it's not a match and the `_id` is used in an attempt to insert. You can only query using fields other than `_id` with upserts.

Comment: Ok @Neil Lunn, I understood. Thank You